# ToUnixTimeSeconds method missing after migration to VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

```
var item = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

The code causes the compilation error **"Does not contain a definition for ToUnixTimeSeconds..."**.
It works well in VS 2015, also I have `using System;` namespace and references to both mscorlib and System (4.0.0.0 version). Many other members of DateTimeOffset exist.

Comment: try to run `dotnet restore` manually on your project and close-open VS.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Editing based on Eric's comment)

Following APIs were added in .NET Framework 4.6; from [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#v46):

> - Support for converting dates and times to or from Unix time
>
>   The following new methods have been added to the DateTimeOffset structure to support converting date and time values to or from Unix time:
>
>   - [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds)
>   - [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds)
>   - [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds)
>   - [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds)

You can also check the "Applies To" section in official docs to confirm compatibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds#applies-to

Just update your application target framework to framework version 4.6 or higher in project file (`.csproj`):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  <!--
    or multiple frameworks at once:
    <TargetFrameworks>net46,netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks>
  -->
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

then in C# code:

```
public static long UnixTimeNowSec => DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Comment: In other words, [`ToUnixTimeSeconds` was introduced in .NET 4.6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3), so make sure your project targets .NET 4.6 or higher (Properties -> Application -> Target framework).

Answer (score 6):

i recently i have the same problem in a new project. What i do after doing some google search and testing find a function like this one:

```
public static long ToUnixEpochDate(DateTime date) => new DateTimeOffset(date).ToUniversalTime().ToUnixTimeSeconds();

//Usage 
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var result = ToUnixEpochDate(now).ToString();
```

Hope it helps. Also try as @Kiratijuta mention in comment to target .net 4.6 or later.

Comment: This will result in the same error (you're still calling `ToUnixTimeSeconds` in the static method). @Kiratijuta is correct that the project needs to target .NET 4.6 or higher.